# Issues with creating a custom colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, cartopy

I am trying to create a custom colorbar with discrete intervals using this resource (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html), but I am running into this error which references my 'cb2' line in my code:

> Error: "AttributeError: 'GeoContourSet' object has no attribute 'set'"

```
import xarray as xr
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import proplot as pplt
import cartopy as ct
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import colormaps as cmaps
import matplotlib.colors as colors

fig, axs = pplt.subplots(ncols = 2, nrows = 1, axwidth = 7, proj='pcarree')
ax1, ax2 = axs


a = ax1.contourf(era_cape['lon'], era_cape['lat'], regression,  add_colorbar = False, extend = 'both')

axs.format(coast=True, latlim = (20,51), lonlim = (234,293), innerborders = True)
axs.add_feature(ct.feature.OCEAN, zorder=100, edgecolor='k', color = 'white')
axs.add_feature(ct.feature.COASTLINE, zorder=100, edgecolor='k')

cmap1 = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['purple','navy','slateblue','blue','skyblue','lightblue','aliceblue','yellow','gold','orange','orangered','red','firebrick','darksalmon'])
bounds = [-600, -480, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 480, 600]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap1.N, extend = 'neither')
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(a, cmap = cmap1, norm = norm, ticks = bounds, spacing = 'uniform')
```

In this example,
I am relatively new to coding and I am not sure if there is anything I need to do to my data to get it to 'fit' into my custom colorbar.

If I I changed the cb2 line to read:

```
cb2 = fig.colorbar(a, cmap = cmap, norm = norm, ticks = bounds)
```

This gives me a colorbar but it is set to an old, cmap (RdBu) rather than the new one I have created. The ticks are visible but only go up about 1/4 way on the colorbar. If I change the line back to

```
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase()
```

I get the attribute error mentioned above again. In this example, era_cape['lat'] and era_cape['lon'] is 2D data over the United States with data spanning from roughly -600 to 600.

```
{'coords': {'lon': {'dims': ('lon',), 'attrs': {'units': 
'degrees_east', 'short_name': 'lon', 'long_name': 'longitude'}, 
'data': [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 
2.5, 2.75, 3.0, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4.0, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5.0, 5.25, 
5.5, 5.75, 6.0, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7.0, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8.0, 8.25, 
8.5, 8.75, 9.0, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75]}, 'lat': {'dims': ('lat',), 
'attrs': {'qualifier': 'Gaussian', 'units': 'degrees_north', 
'short_name': 'lat', 'long_name': 'latitude'}, 'data': [90.0, 
89.75, 89.5, 89.25, 89.0, 88.75, 88.5, 88.25, 88.0, 87.75, 87.5, 
87.25, 87.0, 86.75, 86.5, 86.25, 86.0, 85.75, 85.5, 85.25, 85.0, 
84.75, 84.5, 84.25, 84.0, 83.75, 83.5, 83.25, 83.0, 82.75, 82.5, 
82.25, 82.0, 81.75, 81.5, 81.25, 81.0, 80.75, 80.5, 80.25]}}, 
'attrs': {'title': 'p_cal_daily2monthly_era5.ncl', 'program'
```

Comment: And you should probably review [ProPlot: Axes colorbars and legends](https://proplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/colorbars_legends.html) if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your sample code, and without data to replicate the error it requires some guessing. So perhaps you can simplify it a little and use toy data (or publicly available otherwise)?

I suspect the error comes from the fact that you pass the result from `ax.contourf` to `mpl.colorbar.ColorBase`. The latter expects an axes object as the argument, and that should be a dedicated axes for the colorbar, not the axes of you actual plot. But instead of an axes, you provide the result of `contourf` (a `GeoContourSet`), which is not appropriate and I'm guessing triggers the error you experienced.

Often more high-level functions are used to avoid having to create a colorbar axes (`cax`) explicitly (see below).

I'm not familiar with proplot myself, so in the example below I have removed it for simplicity. I don't think that matters in the end and you could probably add it back in for the functionality that you need.

A simplified example, focusing on the colorbar specifically, is shown below:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate toy data, example data from:
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, 0.025)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

# scale toy example data to global
lon = x * 180/3
lat = y * 90/3
regression = Z * 300

# define the colormap and scaling
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([
    'purple','navy','slateblue','blue','skyblue','lightblue', 'aliceblue',
    'yellow','gold','orange','orangered','red','firebrick','darksalmon',
])
bounds = [-600, -480, -320, -160, -80, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 480, 600]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# create the figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    1,1, figsize=(8,5), facecolor="w", layout="compressed", 
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()),
)

# plot the contours, note that "cf" is also a mappable that could 
# be used instead of "im" below
cf = ax.contourf(
    lon, lat, regression, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, 
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
)

# create the colorbar
im = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cb = fig.colorbar(
    im, ax=ax, ticks=bounds, spacing="uniform", 
    orientation="horizontal", shrink=0.8,
)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, ec="k", fc="w", zorder=100)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, ec="k", zorder=100)
```

Which results in:
[image]

The use of `fig.colorbar` allows you to pass your main axes (for plotting), and makes Matplotlib automatically create a reasonable colorbar axes for you. You can also provide that axes yourself (`cax=cax`), but that's mainly useful if you need more control on the specific location for example, like placing it in/over your main axes.